# How to open SQL Server Management Studio after installing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How to open SQL Server Management Studio after installing in Windows 10.

I tried to make search using this key word: "How to open SQL Server Management Studio after installing?".

Also tried to pass command SSMS.exe, ssms in CMD.

I need to open SQL Manager to manage my databases.

This is screenshot of installation page:

[image]

Comment: Ok, just hit Win+R, and write 'ssms.exe' and hit enter.

Comment: Can not find ssms.exe

Comment: So you don't have it. [Get one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) :)

Comment: I do have, really

Comment: Did you include "Management Tools" as a chosen option during setup?

Comment: Look updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your SQL Server version, I would highly recommend you to download latest SSMS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). As of this writing its version **17.4**. Microsoft releases new version of **SSMS** every month and I would encourage you to download the latest one because Microsoft fixes some bugs and new features are added. The only downside is you need to reboot your machine every time you update the SSMS.

If you need SQL Server Database Engine installed on your laptop, you can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). You can download SQL Server Express or SQL Server Developer Edition. I would suggest you to download the Developer Edition as it has all the feature of Enterprise edition so you can play around with the features of Enterprise. Use it only for development and testing purpose.

Comment: @Amelia you just need **SSMS 17.4** (latest as of this writing). download it from the link provided in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean I need to download manager cause now I have only SQL Database?

Comment: You need to install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to manage your database. SSMS is a GUI client tool so you can easily manage your database. Your screenshot just shows you only installed the SQL Server 2014 database engine.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Folder Versions]

     80 = SQL Server 2000 
     90 = SQL Server 2005 
    100 = SQL Server 2008 
    105 = SQL Server 2008 R2 
    110 = SQL Server 2012 
    120 = SQL Server 2014 
    130 = SQL Server 2016 
    140 = SQL Server 2017       

Path:   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\[**FolderVersion**]\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe 

Example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
```

If the path does not exist, you will have to download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/developer-tools.aspx)

Comment: Which package select? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Comment: SQLEXPRWT or SQLEXPRADV